# Error: in m_str_extents_(x, fontname, fontsize, bold, italic, fontfile) : function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'

Tags: r, rcpp, gtsummary

I'm using tbl_summary function with as_flex_table() under R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) and  Rstudio Version 1.4.1106  in a R-Markdown project with successfull results. But when I try using the same .Rmd under R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) and Rstudio Version 1.4.1717 I get the following error. **"Error:  in m_str_extents_(x, fontname, fontsize, bold, italic, fontfile) : function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'**" . I get this error when I use the function as_flex_table() only.  Someone knows if the are uncompatibility issues.

**Please help me**

```
table1 <- tbl_summary (data, by=trt)) %>%
  add_n() %>% 
  add_p() %>% 
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>% 
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_caption("Patient Characteristics") %>% 
  as_flex_table()
```

Comment: Based on the error message, perhaps updating your Rcpp package would help?

Comment: I have already updated it and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic function `m_str_extents_()` is from `gdtools`. So likely you have a recent version or `gdtools` compiled against an older version of `Rccp`. Try updating `Rccp` to version 1.0.7 with `install.packages()` and with a bit of hope it should work.

```r
install.packages("Rcpp")
```

For reference same problem described [on Rccp mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/rcpp-devel@lists.r-forge.r-project.org/msg10226.html) which can summarised with

> TL;DR: update your library.